# When I submit the form I get this error org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

When I submit the form I get this error - "org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value",
Please help. I referred similar questions to this in stackoverflow, but I couldn't resolve

//User Class below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(nullable=false, unique = true, length = 45)
    private String email;
    
    @Column(nullable=false, length = 64)
    private String password;
    
    @Column(nullable=false, length = 20)
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(nullable=false, length = 20)
    private String lastName;
    
        
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
        
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your User class has no other entities associated, it seems like at least one of the email, password, first or last name properties is null when submitting the form. You should check, before saving the User class if any of these properties is null, you should get your answer there.